# No puedo pasar una variable a un txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Tengo un pequeño programa, el cual interactua con una página web y recoge un texto, adjuntado debajo del código, este texto lo imprimo por pantalla, pero a la hora de pasarlo a un txt no se escribe, el fichero esta en blanco, pero sin embargo si que se imprime en la terminal.

```
 # finds all <p> on the web page and prints them.
    descripciones = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    for descripcion in descripciones:
        texto = descripcion.text
        
        Eliminado_Parrafo_Final_1 = texto.find("Siamo la più grande rete")
        descripcion_final_1 = texto[:Eliminado_Parrafo_Final_1]

        print(descripcion_final_1) 

    file = open("Temp.txt", "w")
    file.write(descripcion_final_1)
    file.close()
```

Texto :

```
Inver
Riscaldamento (SCOP)
Raffreddamento (SEER) 
Deumidificazione indipende
Flusso aria
Smart kit per controllo internet opzion
LISTINI
RISERV

ASSISTENZA
SPECIALIZZ

SPEDIZIONE
TRACCIABILE E GARANT

Potenza termica dell`apparecchio in kW in modalità raffreddamento a pieno regime: 3.
Consumo energetico/anno (in kWh/anno) modalità raffreddamento: 183
Classe di efficienza modalità riscaldamento:
Potenza termica dell`apparecchio in kW in modalità riscaldamento a pieno regime: 3.
Consumo energetico/anno (in kWh/anno) modalità riscaldamento: da 684 a 870
Refrigerante R32 | 675Kg
SEER
SCOP
Interno: pressione sonora 36dB~42dB; soglia rumore 46dB~5
Esterno: pressione sonora 52dB; soglia rumore 6



SPEDIZIONI RAPIDE E TRACCI
```

He añadido la codificación y el retorno de carro en el bucle `for`, pero sigue sin darme resultado.

```py
file = open("Temp.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") 
file.writelines(f"{descripcion_final_1}\n") 
file.close()
```

Comment: Pero que pasa? No se escribe? Se escribe de manera incorrecta? O que?

Comment: ¿Recoge cual texto?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tu `print()` está dentro de un bucle, por lo que se ejecutará posiblemente varias veces generando un texto diferente en cada print. En cambio tu  `write` está fuera del bucle, por lo que mostararía solo el valor final de la variable impresa. Además faltaría añadir un retorno de carro tras la línea escrita en disco (aunque no es estrictamente necesario, es posible que el editor en que intentas verlo después no muestre nada porque falta ese retorno de carro)

Comment: He añadido la codificacion y el retorno de carro en el bucle for, pero sigue sin darme resultado.
file = open("Temp.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") 
file.writelines(f"{descripcion_final_1}\n")
file.close()